# First born male dies on (or before) 25th birthday

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book I've started reading when I was a child. Sadly, I can't remember too many plot details, as I've only had access to the 1st part. What I'm sure about:

- there was a family curse causing first born males in the family to die on (or, perhaps, before) they turn 25 (or was it 21)
- the story begins with a guy from said family sharing the story of the curse with his female friend
- that guy got a letter with a symbol and a part of the plot is him and his friend trying to figure out what is that symbol - turns out it's a Maltese cross

The book's been split into several parts but it might've been only the case in my country (Poland).

I've read it in early 2000s probably, maybe before.

Thanks!

Comment: You say 'my country' - was the book originally from there, or translated into your language?

Comment: Translated into, most likely. I wish I were sure. As far as I can recall the people's names were in English (but I may be horribly wrong here, I'm sorry)

Comment: No problem! You might want to include the country in question in your post, and then it might help jog someone's memory. Every detail helps!

Comment: There are parts similar to H.P. Lovecraft's short story The Alchemist.